# Update following site import leads to fatal error

Tags: error, server, installation

Today, I have moved a fully up-to-date installation to a new server, and three times now on a seemingly successful installation, after going to update to the latest version (the existing install is up to date) I have got a "fatal error".

Any help on where to find what's going wrong so I am not going around in circles any longer would be wonderful.

Comment: Errors should be logged to `path/to/installation/storage/logs/web.log`. There should be a “stack trace” in there, starting with some kind of error message, followed by multiple numbered lines describing the source of the issue. If you can track that down, update your question with those lines, and it shouldn't take much to identify a fix.

Comment: The latest error seems to allude to

`2021-11-06 22:32:35 [-][301][-][warning][craft\services\Plugins::init] Invalid plugin base path: /storage/av08251/www/public_html/vendor/workingconcept/craft-cloudflare/src
2021-11-06 22:32:35 [-][301][-][info][application] $_GET = [
    'p' => 'admin/actions/users/session-info'
    'dontExtendSession' => '1'`

That plugin is not installed, so the folder didn't exist on the existing install.

Comment: I went back and saw that plugin was only turned off, not removed, so went and removed it, re-exported the database and imported, but I'm now getting error 500 instead.

Comment: This is the error i'm now seeing:

`PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/storage/[username]/www/public_html/vendor/composer/../cakephp/core/functions.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /storage/[username]/www/public_html/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 71`

without the full path I don't know exactly which file needs to be found for the site to appear.

Comment: Whoa, uhh… I'm not sure why `cakephp` would be a dependency here… never seen an error like this, before! Are you able to log in and ensure that your `vendor` directory is up-to-date with `composer.lock`? (Sorry for the delayed response!)